# How to filter duplicate logs from mongodb query using python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

```
{u'field': u'error_starting_process', u'_id':ObjectId('56c2ec225141a3121900188e'), u'severity': u'major', u'description': u'Process failed to start.'}

{u'field': u'process_not_running', u'_id': ObjectId('56c2ec226715991f2000197e'), u'severity': u'minor', u'description': u'Process Asset on host  should be running but is not.'}

{u'field': u'process_not_running', u'_id': ObjectId('56c2ec2411debd2b1e0022dd'), u'severity': u'minor', u'description': u'Process Timer Task Execution on host  should be running but is not.'}

{u'field': u'error_starting_process', u'_id': ObjectId('56c2ec24df312f091c0021b0'), u'severity': u'major', u'description': u'Process failed to start.'}
```

How to filter duplicate description ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) method and then retrieve the first document matching each description. e.g:

```
for desc in db.collection.distinct("description"):
    doc = db.collection.find({"description":desc })[0]
```